# What ports are used by component services?

Tags: com+

We’ve got some old COM+ components I wrote, which we’re migrating to a new environment. The hosting service is opening up ports to allow communication. They’ve already opened up port 135, which apparently is used by component services to communicate back to the client, but it seems as though the client maybe using ports above 50,000 when initiating the conversation. Is that true? (I don’t remember anymore, as it was over 10 years ago that I wrote these components. And since we did everything in-house having to open up ports wasn’t anything I had to concern myself with at the time.)

Comment: Is this for MSDTC?  Usually ports 5000-5020 would be used for that: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/250367 .

Comment: I don't think it used MSDTC, because it's not a distributed transaction. Interesting question, though, that might be the case.